# Problemas com imagem no site

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Olá, pessoal quero colocar uma imagem no cabeçalho do meu site, porem não consigo que ela fique no cabecalho certinho. Se eu colocoo codigo antes da div, ela não aparece, seu eu coloco ela na div responsavel pelo titulo, ela aparece. 
Anexei as imagens de como está ficando e o codigo.

```html
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  
 imagem antes, não parece nada   
      
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <div style="background-image:url(views/forum.jpg)">

          imagem aparece pela metade!
          
  
    <center><h1><b><font color="#00c6d7">ALLDISPOR</font></h1></b>
    
    <p>Fórum de Discussão</p></center>
    <br><br><br>
  </div></div>
```

[image: Imagem pela metade, dps da div jumb...]

[image: Imagem com codigo antes da div, não aparece nada]

Comment: Tente definir a altura. background-image:url(views/forum.jpg); height:400px;"

Comment: Sem resultado! :/

Comment: Revise seu código pois toda estrutura está errada, cadê o fechamento de <nav do bootstrap?

Comment: Se o css do bootsrap estiver sendo carregado corretamente o float e margin é automático.

Comment: @denis, realmente se o bootstrap estiver certo não deveria ser isto, corrigi minha resposta, desculpa o incomodo haha

Comment: o nav é fechado bem mais abaixo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@edit De uma olhada na sua estrutura, ou no caminho de sua imagem.
Indico também que de uma olhada na semântica do HTML5 e CSS3, a tag center por exemplo está `deprecated`. Use tudo o que for de estilo em um arquivo de css

```css
.background {
  background:url(https://unsplash.it/900/200/?random);
}
h1 {
  text-align:center;
}
p {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  
 imagem antes, não parece nada   
      
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="background">
      imagem aparece pela metade!
      <h1>ALLDISPOR</h1>
      <p>Fórum de Discussão</p>
      <br/><Br/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se sua estrutura segue o padrão correto, carregando todas bibliotecas necessárias. Veja documentação do Bootstrap http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Abaixo um exemplo:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>ALLDISPOR</h1>
  <p>Fórum de Discussão.</p> 
  <figure>
      <img src="views/forum.jpg" />
  </figure>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Denis usei essa estrutura que você passou, e deu razoavelmente certo, só não estou conseguindo aumentar o tamanho do container, o que seria?

Comment: troque a classe container-fluid por uma classe que você determine o tamanho pelo css. A classe container-fluid vai respeitar o tamanho do que tem dentro dela.

Answer (score 0):

Isso fará com que toda a div seja preenchida pela imagem.

```
imagem antes, não parece nada        

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div style="background-image:url(views/forum.jpg);width:100%;height:100%">

      imagem aparece pela metade!


<center><h1><b><font color="#00c6d7">ALLDISPOR</font></h1></b>

<p>Fórum de Discussão</p></center>
<br><br><br>
```